# How can I queue a background task from a unit test in confidence it'll complete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, unit-testing

We have a set of integration tests which create data in a database and need to clean up the data as part of tear down. I know the data is always unique for the particular test so won't affect subsequent tests. I therefore want to process the cleaning up of this data in a background thread to reduce impact on other tests.

I reluctantly tried including the `System.Web` assembly and using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` to do this but as suspected this didn't work:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.'

I tried placing my code in an async method and not awaiting but as suspected the test completed and terminated the process before completing the tear down.

So what is the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can't use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundItem` because you aren't running in an ASP.NET context.

Comment: There's a way to run nunit tests concurrently, but I don't know if it also works for TearDown: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XUnit or MSTest, you *can* have `async` test methods, but they must return a `Task` object:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestFooAsync() {

     Int32 someValue = await someSource.GetValueAsync();
     Assert( 123, someValue );
}
```

Using `async void` means "fire-and-forget", that's why it should only be used in event-handlers, and not tests.